# mysqli not installed with PHP 8.0.30 (MAC)

Tags: php, mysqli, homebrew

I'm trying to connect my php web application to mysqli for a school project, but mysqli does not seem to be installed. When I try to run my localhost8080 I get:
[mysqli error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYlsL.png)

I was under the impression of my instructor that mysqli is part of PHP and automatically installed with php. I have the extension uncommented out in my .ini file. I have tried reinstalling php with:

```
brew tap shivammathur/php
brew reinstall shivammathur/php/php@8.0
```

This hasn't worked. I am a beginner to this sort of thing and would appreciate any info. I see a couple solutions for windows, but none for mac (Sonoma)

Comment: "I was under the impression of my instructor that mysqli is part of PHP and automatically installed with php" - Generically speaking this is not true, however I think that brew usually does ship with it by default. Try running `php -m` to see the full list of extension. Also, I could be wrong (since I don't use brew), but because they statically link extensions, I think you want the extension to remain commented out in the php.ini file, but maybe someone with brew experience can weigh in on that.

Comment: With php -m I see mysqli in there, I installed php with homebrew and when i do brew list, its not there. I think mysqli should be at /opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20200930/mysqli but its not there

Comment: Do you have it commented out in php.ini, too?

Comment: Yes, I commented out extension=mysqli

Comment: So when it is commented out, do you still get the "unable to load dynamic library" message?

Comment: Yes, its the same error

Comment: @Jimjones did you also remember to restart the server after making changes to php.ini?

Comment: Yes I did. I think the main issue is the mysqli library is not in my pecl location as it should be when installing with homebrew. There is a folder mysql in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@8.0/8.0.30_2/include/php/ext/mysqli but it appears to just be a header file. I am still missing the library itself

Comment: @Jimjones By "commented out" do you mean you removed the comment (#) that was already there or added one? For clarification. Because you are supposed to remove the comment character. Just checking.

Comment: I removed the ; that was in front of the extension=mysqli

Comment: I got it to work from a comment on a different post The ini entry extension=mysqli.so is required if mysqli is compiled as a shared extension.

All PHP brew formulae compile mysqli statically with the PHP binary, so this line is not required and should be removed. That will remove the PHP Warning you are getting.

Then, to check if mysqli is loaded correctly, you can run the php -m command.

Comment: @Jimjones that should really be added as a proper Answer, in the box below. Then it's searchable, and people can upvote your answer if they find it useful themselves. Right now your post still appears to be unanswered (comments don't count) and people can't find your answer (because comments aren't searchable). See also [answer] (and also the [tour], as you're new). Glad you found a solution btw :-)